# Handlebar Internal Weight Bar too long, but is correct part

Tags: motorcycle, replace, fit, replacements, handlebars

A while back I crashed the bike, and I've been doing it up in piecemeal fashion. When I came to replace the scratched handlebar weights, I found the internal bar had snapped, at the location of the blue arrow on the picture.

The remaining portion of the bar didn't hold the shiny new weight - the weight would loosen and fall out whilst riding. So I purchased a whole new bar.

**Old vs New Internal Weight Bar**
[image]

---

Seems simple enough, but I've found the new bar doesn't fit. It's too long. It sticks out by about an inch.

But it's the same length as the old bar? Yes.

So I tried the old bar back in, and that doesn't fit either. Now that makes no sense, because it obviously fitted before the crash.

There is nothing stuck up inside the hollow of the handlebar.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Either explain what might be happening, or suggest a fix, or suggest what might be wrong?

---

**New Bar Sticks Out**
[image]

**Size Comparison External**
[image]

**Nothing Inside Hollow of Handlebar**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that split ring compresses when the weight bar is pushed in the handle bar which then keeps it in place. Have you tried tapping it in with a rubber mallet or something similar?

Comment: I removed the rubber gommit (on the far left in the first picture) in order to remove "effort" from the equation. The bar slides in and out easily without that grommit (but doesn't stay in) so when it stops, it stops - and I assume it is hitting up against the final "wall" inside the hollow.

Comment: Dammit! How stupid do I feel! I removed the split ring as well as the grommit, and it just slides right in, all the way!  Doh!  :/